# On linear schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve and $T$ is any smooth variety. Let $E$ be a family of vector bundles over $X\times T$ which is flat over $T$. Then there exists a scheme $Y$ over $T$ such that for any $f:S\rightarrow T$
the set of $S$-valued points of $Y$ is $H^0(X\times S, f^*E)$. It is called a linear scheme over $T$.

Is $Y$ always a Cohen–Macaulay or local complete intersection?

Comment: What do you mean by a "linear scheme over $X$"?

Comment: @Sasha added a definition, thanks.

Comment: Before you had a linear scheme over $X$, now you define a linear scheme over $T$, haven't you confused anything?

Comment: @Sasha No this is a correct definition. I am sorry for the notations. Please forget what I wrote earlier.

Comment: Are there any hypotheses on $T$? If $E = \mathcal O_{X \times T}^n$, then $Y = \mathbf A^n_T$ (if I understand correctly), so at least you'd want $T$ itself to be Cohen–Macaulay or whatever your desired conclusion is. Or is the question about whether the map $Y \to T$ is syntomic or something like that?

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn thanks, yes I also assume T to be smooth